# When can I up-vote an unanswered question?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, up-votes

Sometimes I see question on the Unanswered tab, that have a few good answers, but none of them is up-voted. I know that if I up-vote one of the answers, the question won't be on the Unanswered tab anymore, and I feel it might be the place of the question asker to decide when his/her question has been answered.
So what should my criteria be about up-voting unanswered questions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> So what should my criteria be about up-voting unanswered questions?

Nothing else than up-voting other questions/answers... You should always up-vote when you see an answer or question that is useful (see also the mouse over text). No other criteria should play a role here!

Answer (score -2):

The answer status is define by the tick mark. Not the votes.

EDIT: And BTW only the author can put the tick.

Comment: No it isn't. I don't know the exact criteria to be on the unanswered tab, but it aren't only the questions that don't have an accepted answer for sure!

Comment: this is not true. In a post from thier blog, Jeff says: "As of today, here’s how we do it:

    * Answered questions have at least one answer with one upvote (or accepted)
    * Unanswered questions have no answers with upvotes (or accepted) " http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/ok-now-define-answered/

Comment: Hum interesting @Lea. Didn't saw that one.